# Visual Studio: how to get output in "Win32" project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to write a simple program that would find all open windows and display their window names; however, in Visual Studio under a "Win32 Project", the console isn't there to output anything by the "cout" function.

But if I were to attempt to put the code under a "Win32 Console" project, I get errors about external dependencies (so I'm assuming I just can't do that?).

So is there any way I can add the console to a "Win32" project?

The code in question (unfinished, of course):

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lparam){
    LPTSTR title = 0;

    GetWindowText(hwnd, title, sizeof(title));
    cout << "Window Name: " << endl;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Last but not least, the erros I get when I attempt to run the code in a "Win32 console" project.

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\justin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exe 1   1   ConsoleApplication5
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   c:\Users\Justin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)   ConsoleApplication5
```

Comment: You can do this in a Win32 console project. [This works for me](https://ideone.com/KOv05K), VS2012 but it honestly should work in 2010, 2008, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you console project the main function has to be called main, not WinMain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lparam)
{
    LPTSTR title = 0;

        GetWindowText(hwnd, title, sizeof(title));
        std::cout << "Window Name: " << std::endl;

        return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) // SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
//int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) // SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
{
        EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);

        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

This will work for a Win32 console application project. It's exactly your code but I changed the signature of the WinMain function to be the standard main.

To know which of the two you should use, check the following setting: `Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem`, if this is set to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` it will expect the standard main signature, if it is set to `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` it will expect the WinMain one.

Comment: I was wondering if it can be done, because in OpenGL when I use GLUT API for displaying windows, i use int main(), and it is a console application, but GLUT internally uses win32 calls. 

I got it working in my program now.
My question> but is this really a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

In a non-console application you can use the API call `AllocConsole` (and its buddy `FreeConsole`) to create (and destroy) a console window.  Usually this is done for debugging purposes.

There are a number of functions that allow you to control the console window as well.  See the [Console reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

In addition, the standard output is tied to the console, so that you can write to it using `cout` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

As an Autoit user I really do not like the lack of basic functions that make life easier. If you still want to use the standard console `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`  in win32 gui Windows `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` project, I would suggest you to use this file:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>


FILE *g_ic_file_cout_stream; FILE *g_ic_file_cin_stream;

// Success: true , Failure: false
bool InitConsole() 
{
    if (!AllocConsole()) { return false; }
    if (freopen_s(&g_ic_file_cout_stream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout) != 0) { return false; } // For std::cout 
    if (freopen_s(&g_ic_file_cin_stream, "CONIN$", "w+", stdin) != 0) { return false; } // For std::cin
    return true;
}
```

Save it as InitConsole.h .

In your code area, First `#include "InitConsole.h"`. then - before you use `std::cout`, first call to `InitConsole();`.
Make sure that it didn't return false. If it return false then it failed to create and initialize the console.

In addition, it will not trigger the annoying warning in VS 2015.

I do not understand why there is not such a basic function. I suggest you keep this file for reuse in the future for any win32 gui project (for debugging purpose).

**NOTE: I am very new in C++ so if I did something wrong in the code, then fixes are more then welcome.**

**EDIT: `std::cin` is not working. I would love if someone will improve this code and make it also work. Anyway it is stil good**

**UPDATE: Code updated to support `std::cin` functionality**